# C# Dictionary As Application Cache

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, grouping

I don't even know if I am on the right track but I gave a shot to Dictionary to store big and static data (like multi language data) and use it in the whole application. This example goes for a WinForms app.

In this scenario, I have a table which holds various parameters, divided into groups. The table is made of following fields: GROUP_CODE, PARAMETER_KEY, PARAMETER_VALUE... It simply holds lots of values as in this example:

GROUP_CODE: 'MAILING_INFO'
PARAMETER_KEY: 'SendMailAfterProcessIsDone'
PARAMETER_VALUE: 'a@b.com'

There is no problem or anything to hold and get the data from the database. My only problem is that how exactly I am going to handle this data...

My ParameterValues class holds the following, same fields I select from the table...

```
public class ParameterValues
{
    private string groupCode;
    private string parameterKey;
    private string parameterValue;

    public string GroupCode
    {
        get { return groupCode; }
        set { groupCode = value; }
    }

    public string ParameterKey
    {
        get { return parameterKey; }
        set { parameterKey = value; }
    }

    public string ParameterValue
    {
        get { return parameterValue; }
        set { parameterValue = value; }
    }
}
```

In another class, called **CacheHelper**, I am trying to put this object with the GROUP_CODE value as key into a Dictionary. (Hope that made sense)

```
public class CacheHelper
{
    public Dictionary<string, ParameterValues> LoadParameterCache2()
    {
        //Dictionary<string, ParameterValues> objList = new Dictionary<string, ParameterValues>();

        Dictionary<string, List<ParameterValues>> objList = new Dictionary<string, List<ParameterValues>>();

            //call the values from the database blah blah
            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                ParameterValues cacheObj = new ParameterValues();
                cacheObj.ParameterKey = rdr.GetString("PARAMETER_KEY");
                cacheObj.ParameterValue = rdr.GetString("PARAMETER_VALUE");
                objList.Add(rdr.GetString("GROUP_CODE"), /*List ParameterValues goes here blah blah*/);
            }


        return objList; //and finally return it to the main application thread
    }
}
```

I have to group it by GROUP_CODE values as from the database since Dic's "key" has to be unique... I know....

Since I think it was not clear enough, I tried to demonstrate what I am actually trying to do in the following image...

[image: What I want is something like this...]

I simply cannot put it there groupped. Please someone show me a way... And also I'd like to hear your ideas if this is a good way to use this as application caching for really large data (thousands of rows I mean).

Many thanks!

Comment: You may want to look at a [`KeyedCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx) that lets you use the `GroupCode` parameter as the key to the dictionary and you don't need to manually set it as the key. However that does not solve your problem of uniqueness as KeyedCollection has the same restriction as Dictionary on its keys, just wanted to let you know abou the type.

Comment: Your method signature does not match your return type.

Comment: System.Runtime.Caching has a MemoryCache class for handling application caching needs. I've used it for lots of large things, including localization strings.

Comment: @StingyJack that was not the point anyway haha... Well but can I use this in ASP.Net applications as well?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I simply cannot put it there groupped"? Why not? Do you get an error or does something else not work?

Comment: MS pulled the Asp.net caching stuff into the system.runtime.caching namespace so it could be used by any .net app.

Comment: What I don't understand is how you are using your data structure and what the actual problem is. Are you trying to map a single group_code (e.g. MAILING_INFO) to multiple ParameterValues? Or is it 1-1? Your question is missing an important piece of information. Are you not sure how to implement the "/*List ParameterValues goes here blah blah*/" section?

Comment: @TomA exactly, sorry I actually missed that part out... This is supposed to be a 1-n relationship... I guess I found something, I'm working on it right now, something about Linq...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to talk about caching solutions, as there are some out there and I am not particularly experienced with any.

But If you want to try static Dictionary solution, you could try grouping your data using Linq:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<ParameterValues>> LoadParameterCache2()
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, ParameterValues>> dataValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ParameterValues>>();

    // Your code to produce the DataReader
    DataTableReader rdr = GetDataReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        ParameterValues cacheObj = new ParameterValues();
        cacheObj.ParameterKey = (string)rdr["PARAMETER_KEY"];
        cacheObj.ParameterValue = (string)rdr["PARAMETER_VALUE"];

        KeyValuePair<string, ParameterValues> dataValue = new KeyValuePair<string, ParameterValues>((string)rdr["GROUP_CODE"], cacheObj);

        dataValues.Add(dataValue);
    }

    Dictionary<string, List<ParameterValues>> objList = dataValues.GroupBy(d => d.Key).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select(i => i.Value).ToList());

    return objList;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I get where you are having a problem, please note the syntax may be not 100% as I am typing from memory.

```
public class CacheHelper
{
  public Dictionary<string, List<ParameterValues>> LoadParameterCache2()
  {
       var objList = new Dictionary<string, List<ParameterValues>>();

        //call the values from the database blah blah
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

            var cacheObj = new ParameterValues();
            cacheObj.ParameterKey = rdr.GetString("PARAMETER_KEY");
            cacheObj.ParameterValue = rdr.GetString("PARAMETER_VALUE");

 //here is where you need to change things.
            var groupCode = rdr.GetString("GROUP_CODE");
            if (objList.ContainsKey(groupCode) == false)
            {
               objList.Add(groupCode, new List<ParameterValues> {cacheObj});
            }
            else 
            {
               objList[groupCode].Add(cacheObj);
            }
        }


    return objList; //and finally return it to the main application thread
  }
}
```